# Skip array insertion on looping

Tags: php, arrays, loops

How to skip inserting into an array if last value is equal to new coming value? below code produced 12345555555667 but I just want 1234567, means not a value is duplicate.

```
$NumArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7');
$SecondArray = array();

foreach($NumArray as $num){
    $SecondArray[] = array(
    'alpa'=>$num
    );
}

echo json_encode($SecondArray);
```

Comment: "if last value is equal to new coming value"

Comment: http://php.net/end   `if (end($arr) != $new_value) { $arr[] = $new_value }`

Comment: [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)?

Comment: little note: you could spare the first row which just initializes the array

Comment: @Daan I'm not able to comprehend this. Someone with better understanding of what he's trying to convey should rewrite the question.

Comment: You should have searched google before posting this question
please check [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
$NumArray = array();

$numArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7');

foreach($NumArray as $num){
    if ($previousNumber != $num) {
       echo $num;
       $previousNumber = $num;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would discourage the use of `continue` tough and just invert the condition inside the `if` statement.

Comment: $NumArray = array('1','2','1'

Comment: @b.enoit.be: Why you would discourage the use of `continue`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that makes code harder to review (e.g. if the `foreach` grow bigger). As I would also not recommend `break` in loops. 
You are also forcing a reviewer to thing 'backwards' which is not straightforward. -> In this case, when I reach the `echo` I have to go back on the precedent line, think what is the inverted condition which is going to make this line executed, and that is not allowing me, as a reviewer to understand a code in 'one go'.

Comment: this solution is very limited for only this case, please consider using [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$NumArray = array();

$NumArray  =array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7');
$NumArray = array_unique($NumArray) ;
foreach($NumArray as $num){
echo $num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get unique values of an array then iterate on them.

```
$NumArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7');

$unique_arr = array_unique($NumArray) ;

foreach($UniqueArray as $num){
    echo $num;
}
```

Comment: Or just echo `implode(" ", array_unique($NumArray));`

Comment: Note that this way will fail if the array is not sorted.

Comment: It will not fail even its not sorted, PHP selects unique values of all elements in the array

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
$NumArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7');
$NumArray = array_unique($NumArray);
```

even:

```
$NumArray = array_unique(array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure only unique elements are added when you are first populating the array. Edit :

```
if (!in_array($someNewValue, $NumArray))
{
    $NumArray[] = $someNewValue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/array_unique)

```
$numArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7');
echo json_encode(array_unique($numArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <count($NumArray); $i++) 
{
  for ($k = $i+1; $k <count($NumArray); $k++) 
  {
    if ($k != $i && $NumArray[$i] == $NumArray[$k]) 
      {
        $NumArray[$k]="";
      }
  }
}
```

Now the array 'NumArray' contains atomic values only.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (end($NumArray) != $someNewValue){
    $NumArray = $someNewValue;
}
```

Comment: By last value they mean the last value that was looped through, not the last value in the array.

Comment: true. I did not understand question.